# Extract an integer value from array and program without showing printf function

Tags: c, arrays, integer, printf, atoi

I want to extract a number from an array I introduce in the keyboard and convert it into one integer. My code is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int r, t, i;
    char expressio[t];
    char vector[50];
    char rpn[t][4];

    printf("Introduce the expresssion");
    fgets(expressio, t, stdin);

    t = strlen(expressio);

    for (i = 0; i <= t; i++) {
        if (isdigit(expressio[i])) {
            r = atoi(expressio[i]);
            vector[i] = rpn[0][r];
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I have this warning:

> passing argument 1 of 'atoi' makes pointer from integer without a cast

How can i solve it?

Also, when I execute this program, it does nothing and it doesn't even print the "Introduce the expression". Why is this happening?

Comment: Please enable complier warnings and deal with them as if errors! `t` is undefined. And please look up the man page for `atoi`.

Comment: Try to build your code with `-Wall -O2` arguments, it will show you 4 more warnings you should fix before even start to think why your code doesn't work properly. As for `atoi()` warning -- look at [man atoi](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi): it expects you to provide a **pointer** to `const char` (i.e. string), but you are providing it with `char` instead.

Comment: Look at the loop, you accidentally put the return in it, thus exiting your program. And the reason why you don't see the "Introduce the expression" is because the output in c is stored in a  FILE called stdout  which only updates when it is flushed, stdout is normally flushed with a newline or upon program exit. Try adding \n to introduce the expression to see it during run time and not after the program finishes

Comment: Regarding the code I'd check if all the input is digits and then use atoi,  also remeber atoi recieves a string pointer so it must be zero terminated('\0') and  you must call it with a pointer atoi(expressio[i]) is the char in the i position and not a pointer atoi(&expressio[i]) will be a pointer( a memory position) but it still won't work since the logic of the program isn't right. If you keep on having problems let me know and I'll post your code fixed up, but give it a try to fix it first.

Answer (score 0):

That warning means that you are passing a bad argument to the function. "atoi" is expecting an array of chars as argument, but you are passing a single char as argument here:

```
r = atoi(expressio[i]);
```

If you want to convert a single char into a number, you can do:

```
r = expressio[i] - '0';
```

If you look at the ascii table, you will notice that the ascii value of 0 is 48. If you substract 48 (or, like i did, the ascii value of 0) to your char expressio[i], you will get the corresponding number as an integer. Like this, if expressio[i] equals '8', then r will equal 8.